# Send multiple messages in ASP

Tags: email, asp-classic, message

After an internal form is submitted, I want an email to go to the form-filler with specific information and then a new email sent to the customer with different information. As of right now, with what I have, I can make the first email go, but how do I reset the mailer and do it all over again on the same page?

I can make it work if I double-up the code below, but the AddAddress list doesn't reset. The recipients added in the first iteration will still be on the AddAddress list for the second iteration.

This is what I have so far:

```
            message= "<html><body><table><tr><td>Blah blah blah</td></tr>"
            message=message & "<tr><td>Something something.</td></tr>"
            message=message & "</table></body></html>"

           Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
           Mail.Host = "domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"
           Mail.From = "website@domain.com"
           Mail.FromName = "person@domain.com"
           Mail.AddAddress "me@domain.com"
           Mail.Subject = "Gast Repair. Enter P21 order for: " & request.form("CompanyName") 
           Mail.Body = message 
           Mail.IsHTML = True          
           strErr = ""
           bSuccess = False
           On Error Resume Next ' catch errors
           Mail.Send ' send message
           If Err <> 0 Then ' error occurred
              strErr = Err.Description
              'response.write "<P>" & strErr & "</P>"
               else
              bSuccess = True
            'response.redirect sendto
            End If
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure this is ASP.NET? What is the file extension? Is it .aspx or is it .asp?

Comment: Just use `Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")` to re initialise an instance of the object. Depending on how you want to do it and how your data is structured, you could use a loop to avoid duplicating code, the `Set Mail = ...` would be the first line in the loop to guarantee you start with a new instance of the object.

Comment: Persits Mail is a third party component.  I've never used it  but it looks like it's designed to get round the one recipient limit you have with CDO (which is native to Windows Server).  For what you're trying to do you might be better just using CDO. If you call your CDO object "Mail" `Mail.To = "newaddress@domain.com"` will overwrite the original address with the new one.
https://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/web-hosting/send-email-cdosys-example.htm

Comment: @John "one recipient limit" in CDO? You realise the [`To` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-10/ms527328(v=exchg.10)) is just a string so you can do `Mail.To = """Recipient One"" <r1@example.com>, ""Recipient Two"" <r2@example.com>"`.

Comment: @user692942 Then a tutorial I read about fifteen years ago was wrong.  Ah well, it's not the first time that's happened.

Comment: @John tend to stick to the official documentation for that exact reason, lots of misinformation.

Comment: @user692942 I figured I could call up a new Persits.MailSender instance too but when I did that, it wouldn't send the second email at all.

Comment: @mason The file ext is .asp.

Comment: If the file extension is ".asp" then you are not using ASP.NET, you're using Classic ASP. They're completely separate frameworks, and you should not tag your question as `asp.net` but instead `asp-classic`. This helps the right people find your question to answer it, and others with your issue in the future to find your question and hopefully receive an answer.

Comment: @B-Ride I'm not familiar with the `Persits.MailSender` but I've used their `Persits.AspPdf` many times their components are always well documented which looks to be the case here. Just a quick look at [the documentation](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html) shows you should be using the [`Reset()`](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#Reset) method to clear the object completely or [`ResetAddresses()`](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#ResetAddresses) to clear out the address only. I would be starting there.

Answer (score 1):

Why use Persits?

```
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")   
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strOutgoingMailServer
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = strSmtp-auth
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = strSmtp-pass
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60    
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update 
    ObjSendMail.To = "Somebody <somebody@example.com>"
    ObjSendMail.Subject = strSubject
    ObjSendMail.From = strFromName & " <no-reply@example.com>"
    ObjSendMail.ReplyTo = strFromName & " <" & strFromEmail & ">"
    ObjSendMail.BodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8"
    ObjSendMail.TextBody = strEmailBody  
    ObjSendMail.TextBodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8"
    On Error Resume Next
    ObjSendMail.Send
Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
```

Then write a new strEmailBody (message) and run this code again for the new recipient.

If you have problems sending via SMTP server on Windows server, try installing the free hmailServer software.

Answer (score -1):

The [official documentation](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html) for the `Persits.MailSender` COM component provides a few methods;

[`Reset()`](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#Reset)

> Clears all address, attachment and custom header lists so that a new message can be sent.

[`ResetAddress()`](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#ResetAddresses)

> Clears all address lists so that a new message can be sent. Does not clear attachments, embedded images, custom headers or properties.

There is also

[`ResetAll()`](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#ResetAll)

> Same as Reset plus resets all properties to their respective default values.

**Note:** This will completely reset the `Mail` object back to its default values.

I would give these a try.

Comment: Thats what I tried as well, but im not familiar enough with ASP to know where that needs to be placed. At the end of the functio. I assume. Since its a sub function, does it need parameters assigned?

Comment: @B-Ride You want to place `Mail.Reset` after you call `Mail.Send` then add your address again and send the message again.

Comment: When I add Mail.Reset after the Mail.Send, the second email isn't sent at all. The documentation says Reset(). Does there need to be something in the ()?

Comment: @B-Ride Do you call `Send()` again afterwards? All the `Reset()` method does is clear the message out it doesn't send it.

Comment: Yes. I pretty much copied the whole code and created another message to send like what I posted in the OP. That also called the Send function. 

Nevertheless, I got it working. Probably not the most efficient way but it does work.
I just copied the OP and changed the variable "Mail" to "Mail2" and created a new message set with new variables. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Was this helpful?